# Play Framework: Cannot import generated sources (src_managed)?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm using this example https://github.com/slick/slick-codegen-example to generate sources based on my SQL schema. The generation finishes successfully but I'm unable to import them in my controller. Eclipse does not complain and is able to resolve the "Tables" class. But for some reason when I compile using 'play' console, it fails with this error:

```
[error] /..../app/controllers/Application.scala:7: object Tables is not a member of package models
[error] import models.Tables
[error]        ^
```

Comment: I had to manually copy the Tables.scala file to the actual src/models directory. For some reason the compiler is not looking into the scr_managed directory.

Comment: Yes I did the same, but  this is extremely dirty it would be really nice to make this work properly

Comment: It seems this problem is no longer there with the recent versions of Slick. Now however eclipse is confused about the same thing but not sbt.

Comment: My default sbt setup still put it in `src_managed`.  So I reset the output directory to use `outputDir = ((sourceDirectory in Compile).value).getPath`.  In a Play App it will end up in `/app/[targetPackageName]/Tables.scala.  I don't know why it ends up in src_managed because the slick-codegen-example recommends it should end up under source control.